# Button click not working

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, localization

I have a web application in multi language .

In this application I have a web page that contains a text box for book name,and a button to update book name to database.

When a text box contains the Dutch words button is not getting clicked. It's working fine with the English words.

Dutch words like: Grün und  für Gebäuden behagliche, angenehm warme oder kühle Bedingungen.

**Error message upon button click:**

> i'm getting following exception on button :Microsoft JScript runtime error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: An unknown error occurred while processing the request on the server. The status code returned from the server was: 500

Comment: btw that looks like German, not Dutch.

Comment: Post the resulting code for the dutch page (view source in the browser) ... maybe just by doing that you'll see the error

Comment: It is german, not dutch.

Comment: @Dennis Röttger  & @ Piskvor is that issue because my application designed for Dutch and english only

Comment: It'd really help if you could just post your aspx-markup and your Button_Click-Function, otherwise all we can do is play the guessing game and my Crystal Ball is broken atm, so that's no fun for me.

Comment: @PramodChoudhari: Buttons clicks are powered via JavaScript. You probably have some overtranslation, i.e. function name got translated. Also, you might have done something stupid, i.e. pass localizable text in URL without escaping it. No way to tell anything more without the code.

Comment: Funny thing: I have seen a lot of application where people tend to use Dutch as provisioned German strings (mock-ups), they tend to think it is German. Here it is the other way round. Strange.

Comment: @all Thanks for the reply i got actual issue in that page i have TextArea and that control contains as string value which has <BR/><BR/> tag in it. so i'm getting following exception on button :Microsoft JScript runtime error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: An unknown error occurred while processing the request on the server. The status code returned from the server was: 500 how to handle this.?????

Answer (score 2):

Try to put autopostback property as true. Once i have faced such type of situation, I have made autopostback as true and it ran finally.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure when interacting with Database you are using NVarChar, for Unicode characters; albeit your example.

Comment: its not issue of DB. I have my update code on buton click.button is no getting clicked .

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the reply i got actual issue in that page i have TextArea and that control contains as string value which has <BR/><BR/> tag in it. so i'm getting following exception on button :Microsoft JScript runtime error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: An unknown error occurred while processing the request on the server. The status code returned from the server was: 500